# Creating a new variable in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes which all have the structure and variables. Now I want to create a new variable in each dataframe based on another dataframe by only taking the first four digits of that other variable. This is how my comand looks like

```
list.ENAHO_M7 <- lapply(list.ENAHO_M7, function(x) {
  x[, "PROVINCE"] <- str_extract(x[, "UBIGEO"], "^\\d{4}")
})
```

The command itself works fine and does exactly what needed. However it replaces each variable of that dataframe with the results of the command. I guess that it only has to do with the expression of `x[, "PROVINCE"]` referring to the dataframe rather than the variable within the dataframe and should be quite easy to solve. However, I couldn't find the write expression yet.

Comment: Hard to help without a reproducible example, but try putting `x` on a new line between the lines `x[, "PROVINCE"] <- str_extract(x[, "UBIGEO"], "^\\d{4}")` and `})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to return `x`, not `x[, "PROVINCE"]`.

I.e.

```r
lapply(ENAHO_M7, 
       \(x) { x[, "PROVINCE"] <- stringr::str_extract(x[, "UBIGEO"], "\\d{4}"); x }
       )
```

*Note: I've adjusted the `regex` for illustration on my toy data.*

**Output:**

```
$a
  UBIGEO  var2 PROVINCE
1  11110 33330     1111
2  22220 44440     2222

$b
  UBIGEO  var2 PROVINCE
1  55550 77770     5555
2  66660 88880     6666
```

**Toy data:**

```
ENAHO_M7 <-
  list(a = data.frame(UBIGEO = c("11110","22220"), var2 = c("33330","44440")),
       b = data.frame(UBIGEO = c("55550","66660"), var2 = c("77770","88880")))
```